# Android Studio NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, android-studio

I accidentally wrote a main method for a helper class in my project. After I hit run, I stopped it. Now after I have deleted the main method, the project still won't compile, and gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: myproject.UniCourse.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1670)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)
```

Checking out a previous commit in git that worked before doesn't help. Android Studio continues to give me this error message.

What should I do?

Clean & rebuild is not working. (Is this a bug?)

**UPDATE**

I used the last solution I can think of and it worked... I started a new project with the same name and replace the app folder with the old one. Now it's working.

Comment: Did your commit reverted all files? Maybe try to go back more than one commit or attempt to clean the project and rebuid it.

Comment: @Vini No I  ignored some files. I tried going back before the class was introduced, and then clean & rebuild, now it's giving me ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean your project and rebuild it